# Improving FAQ SEO with multiple pages?

Tags: seo, content

I have a client who has over 200 Question/Answer style content blocks. Neither the questions or answers are very long and most of them have almost the same question but with a word or two differentiating themselves from the rest of the questions.

Would SEO be helped or hurt if I would to put each QA on its own page with the title of the page the question being asked etc... Or, would that be considered "farming"?

If not, what would be the best way (in SEO world) do present all these QAs?

Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 Scenarios that you could roll with:

**Scenario 1**: If I have a single page with all the questions and answers in it
then I think of placing the questions in H2 tag and and display the answers in a paragraph element, The title of the page you need to keep generic.

**Scenario 2**: If you generate one separate page for each question, 
then it would be optimum and display the question in your title tag,
this will have more SEO benefits. However you need to be concerned about thin content as this could work as a negative in terms of SEO.

> [Thin content with little or no added value](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/howsearchworks/fighting-spam.html)
>
> Site appears to consist of low-quality or shallow pages which do not
>   provide users with much added value (such as thin affiliate pages,
>   doorway pages, cookie-cutter sites, automatically generated content,
>   or copied content).

Either scenario's are valid, personally I would go with scenario number 2.

Answer (score 2):

"Farming" is when you create a bunch of websites for the explicit purpose of linking to a main website in the hopes of boosting its search engine rankings. You are not doing that here.

Since so many of the questions and answers are similar you may run into duplicate content issues. You also may run afoul of "quality content" issues which is what the Panda update supposedly sought to eliminate.

Your best bet is to create a page for each topic and put all of the questions related to that topic on it. That way you avoid duplicate content penalties, avoid content quality issues, and allow each page to be focused on one topic which helps you optimize it for search terms related to it. It also allows you to have multiple pages which, besides keeping everything organized, allows you to do a lot of cross-linking which is an often overlooked aspect of SEO.

Answer (score 1):

If you could group them logically for the user then i might suggest putting each group on a different page. My general approach to SEO is first to serve the user and Google rank will follow.

Answer (score -1):

## Create New Original Content Only

FAQ Pages should be well ordered and be useful first to the reader. It is often the same amount of energy to cheat the system as it would of been to just do it right. You are trying to find out how to take little content of value and expand it out. Can't be done.  Sure you can change up any article over 80% spun a hundred new ways, though what was the point?

Here is the real issue>  You do not think you have the creativity and brains to write your own interesting material. "You do and then some...believe in yourself and everyone else will too!"

Cheers, Roman